# Using dbghelp.dll on Windows 8.1 Update 1 crashes application

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-8.1, dbghelp

I just updated my version of Windows 8.1 Enterprise to Update 1 (the latest patches released in this week's version of Black Tuesday).

I ran one of my MSVC++ applications which uses WINAPI methods that are a part of dbghelp.dll and it crashed. The only reason I found out was because I checked Event Viewer to see if there were any errors. Surely enough, there were:

```
Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x53458b91
Faulting module name: dbghelp.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16520, time stamp: 0x52e694f8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000e5542
Faulting process id: 0x2220
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf541e52118787
Faulting application path: C:\Code\MyApplication\bin\MyApplication.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
Report Id: 9125099c-c011-11e3-bef2-5c260a3201b8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

So is there a hotfix or a different version of this DLL I should use for 8.1 Update 1?

Comment: There is a new version with the Windows 8.1 SDK and I know that earlier versions are not compatible - just can't find the page where I read it!

Comment: @RogerRowland Looks like the system's DLL is actually 6.3 which is old (latest is 6.12 according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679294(v=vs.85).aspx). I just tried downloading the latest dbghelp version on my system (http://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_EAC=300135395) and grabbed the libs from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64, using the latest dbghelp.lib in the project's linker and putting the latest dbghelp.dll in the bin directory and it worked. Note: Didn't need to do this before the patch! It used to work before!